# How to get this text after a click (selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I can't get a text after a click from the webpage

[Link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=es)

I have a code with selenium that searches a domain name and gives u all the data but when I click on the computer I can't get the data of percentage but I can get the rest of the data.

I tried this:

```
cambiar = brower.find_element_by_id(":8")
cambiar.click()
#puntuacion_ordenador = brower.find_elements_by_class_name("lh-gauge__percentage").text
#puntuacion_ordenador = brower.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='lh-gauge__wrapper lh-gauge__wrapper--pass lh-gauge__wrapper--huge']//div[@class='lh-gauge__percentage']").text
```

I want to get the text from the class name lh-gauge__percentage
The problem it cants is the load of the page because I can take other data from the same page after the click.
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: What are searching ? What is your input text ? Domain name is what I'm asking ?

Comment: For example if Im searching the URL https://www.github.com in the [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=es), my program first analyze the mobile zone and get all the data from that, the i use a click to go to the computer zone but in this zone i can get all the data except the number of the percentage. But in the mobile zone i can take it, and the code of the web page its the same in both zones.

Comment: Can you share your code for mobile zone and computer zone.

Comment: Thank you very much I find the solution the problem was that the web didn't generate the percentage with js so I have to search for multiple elements. Thank you bro!

Comment: Make sure you post your solution as an answer and accept it so the question doesn't remain unanswered.